# Python - Best data structure for incredibly large matrix

Tags: python, data-structures, vector, matrix, large-data-volumes

I need to create about 2 million vectors w/ 1000 slots in each (each slot merely contains an integer).

What would be the best data structure for working with this amount of data? It could be that I'm over-estimating the amount of processing/memory involved.

I need to iterate over a collection of files (about 34.5GB in total) and update the vectors each time one of the the 2-million items (each corresponding to a vector) is encountered on a line.

I could easily write code for this, but I know it wouldn't be optimal enough to handle the volume of the data, which is why I'm asking you experts. :)

Best,
Georgina

Comment: Does it have to be Python? You can get a much more tightly-packed layout in C (or Cython, if you need Python interop). Relatedly, NumPy might be an option.

Comment: This data structure will need 8GB of RAM.  Do you have that much?

Comment: What range of integers do you need to store (smallest and largest possible value)?

Comment: You should tell us more about how you're going to handle the data. With this information, it's hard to give a definite answer.

Comment: Yeah, it could probably be a sparse matrix.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might be memory bound on your machine. Without cleaning up running programs:

```
a = numpy.zeros((1000000,1000),dtype=int)
```

wouldn't fit into memory. But in general if you could break the problem up such that you don't need the entire array in memory at once, or you can use a sparse representation, I would go with `numpy` (`scipy` for the sparse representation).

Also, you could think about storing the data in `hdf5` with `h5py` or `pytables` or `netcdf4` with `netcdf4-python` on disk and then access the portions you need.

Comment: scipy have a specifically structures for sparse matrices, try http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html

Answer (score 1):

Use a sparse matrix assuming most entries are 0.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to work in RAM try the [scipy.sparse matrix](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html) variants. It includes algorithms to efficiently manipulate sparse matrices.